# Ansible read remot_host:port lines from file and verify port is open

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am new to ansible and need help here.

There is a file with 500+ `remote_host:port` line entries like below.

```
remote_host1:port1
remote_host2:port2
remote_host3:port1
```

Using ansible how to loop over the lines from file, split the lines with 2 variables `remot_host` and `port`, login to `remote_host` and using `nc -k -l port` start listening on the `port`, verify connectivity `nc -vz remote_host port` from a given host, kill the `nc` command from remote host.

So gar I have used `wait_for` module to verify connectivity of single `remote_host` and its `port`.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried and what outcome is it producing for you? As written, it sounds like a requirements document, not help with a programming problem

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the file

```sh
shell> cat remote-hosts.txt
test_11:22
test_12:22
test_13:80
```

Use the module [*wait_for*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html). The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - wait_for:
            host: "{{ item.split(':').0 }}"
            port: "{{ item.split(':').1|int }}"
            timeout: 5
          loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'remote-hosts.txt').splitlines() }}"
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ ansible_failed_result.results|selectattr('failed') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [wait_for] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=test_11:22)
ok: [localhost] => (item=test_12:22)
failed: [localhost] (item=test_13:80) => changed=false 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  elapsed: 6
  item: test_13:80
  msg: Timeout when waiting for test_13:80

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    elapsed: 6
    failed: true
    invocation:
      module_args:
        active_connection_states:
        - ESTABLISHED
        - FIN_WAIT1
        - FIN_WAIT2
        - SYN_RECV
        - SYN_SENT
        - TIME_WAIT
        connect_timeout: 5
        delay: 0
        exclude_hosts: null
        host: test_13
        msg: null
        path: null
        port: 80
        search_regex: null
        sleep: 1
        state: started
        timeout: 5
    item: test_13:80
    msg: Timeout when waiting for test_13:80
```